# WPF: Synchronous scrolling becoming sluggish for two DataGrids with one of them having image column with binding

Tags: wpf, image, datagrid, smooth-scrolling, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have two `DataGrid`s and i have synchronous scrolling in place (scrolling on one grid causes other to scroll). One of the grids has a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with `DataTemplate` set to an `Image`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="16">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="CommentIcon_Clicked" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Blank, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

After data is bound to the grids, scrolling becomes very sluggish and slow. Therefore i suspect its the `Source` property binding operation that causes the sluggishness everytime scrolling occurs because if i set the binding to a `StaticResource`, then the scrolling becomes smooth. Is there a way to fix this?

**Update**
The problem is because of the binding errors to the `Image` source. The value of the property that binds to the `Image` source is an empty string:

```
var d2 = (from l in t.Item2
          select new ProgramLine { Blank = String.Emtpty, Line = l}).ToList();
dataGrid2.ItemsSource = d2;
```

This was causing the default converter to fail and hence cause the scrolling to become sluggish because of the property getter getting called everytime the scrolling occurred.

**Lesson learnt**
Like Steven says, make sure there are no binding errors

**Tip**
Use the immediate window when running your WPF application in debug mode

Comment: Have you tried setting Virtualization on your DataGrids?

Comment: Also [Loading image on background](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16035300/1456174) could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for binding errors in the VS Output window.
Also you can use this attached property directly on your binding to image source: `diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High`
Namespace diagnostics is here: `xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"`
After that, you can find even more info about your binding again, in your Output window.
Unfortunately the binding errors are capable of HUGE performance hit. So try to completely eliminate them always when you are working on any WPF application.

Btw you dont have to make your binding `TwoWay`, because `Image` control just cant change the property value back. Its `OneWay` control that just accepts the given value.

EDIT: There are some WPF DataGrid control performance tips you can make use of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764579/improve-wpf-datagrid-performance/13765128#13765128)

Comment: I just used the immediate window (for the first time) to add some elements to my list at runtime and saw these binding errors. After that, i came here to check if there was any answer. After reading your answer and the binding errors, i now know what the problem is! Thank you.