# Better performance from datagrid grouping

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, grouping

I have a DataGrid which I am using with an ICollectionView to group items in a large collection, 20k+ rows in some instances. I have used this approach before with varying success with showing all rows or virtualizing to create a more responsive page. In this instance I would like to virtualize as much as possible to keep the UI responsive. I have used the tips in this answer with little success to my issues.
[Helpful DataGrid Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764579/improve-wpf-datagrid-performance/13765128#13765128)

My main issue is a couple second lag on the DataGrid when loading the data into the ICollectionView View/Source, which I would like to minimize with the proper virtualization. Here is some of my code:

```
<DataGrid Margin="0,2,0,0" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DataView,IsAsync =True}" EnableRowVirtualization ="True" MaxWidth="2560" MaxHeight="1600"
              Grid.Row="2" SelectionMode="Extended" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOutage}">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True" Foreground="{StaticResource Foreground}" Background="{StaticResource AlternatingBackground}">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="300"/>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <!--Follows are DataGrid.ContextMenu and DataGridTextColumns with fixed widths-->
</DataGrid>
```

And c# items:

```
public ICollectionView DataView { get; set; }
private readonly ObservableCollection<EquipmentMonitorRow> equipment = new ObservableCollection<EquipmentMonitorRow>();

DataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(equipment);
DataView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("GroupName"));

equipment.Clear();
//Lag is during this item adding.
equipment.AddRange(data);
```

So hopefully I'm missing some virtualization or maybe I can add the items differently or something.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing my ObservableCollection source to a List source solved the initial load lag.

```
private readonly List<EquipmentMonitorRow> equipment = new List<EquipmentMonitorRow>();
```

Also using a combination of VirtualizingPanel properties I achieved the best virtualization. Specifically if I omitted VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" then the application lagged for almost a minute before showing anything in my DataGrid. The scrolling was a lot better without virtualization but the initial load was unacceptable in my case.

```
VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit ="Item" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Datagrid by default support UI virtualization but as soon as you **apply grouping on ICollectionView, UI virtualization will be turned off**.

You can refer to **[MSDN sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Grouping-and-Virtualization-56e7d3fe)** which basically flattens the grouped list which supports virtualization.

---

**UPDATE for comment:**

> This doesn't specifically mention a collectionview but seems there is
>   virtualization

From the link:

> In a normal WPF ItemsControl that virtualizes, such as ListBox or
>   ListView, virtualization turns off when you turn grouping on.

And DataGrid derives from ItemsControl only, hence UI virtualization is turned off on grouping.

Comment: This doesn't specifically mention a collectionview but seems there is virtualization unless I'm reading it wrong?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588(v=vs.110).aspx#grouped_virtualization